# An unexpected error occurred The plugins file is missing or invalid

Tags: plugins, cypress

I do not have any idea why do I have this error. Everything seems ok. Can you please help me to solve this?

The plugins file is missing or invalid.

Your pluginsFile is set to /Users/gnematova/AMPautomation/AMPautomation/cypress/plugins/index.js, but either the file is missing, it contains a syntax error, or threw an error when required. The pluginsFile must be a .js, .ts, or .coffee file.

Or you might have renamed the extension of your pluginsFile. If that's the case, restart the test runner.

Please fix this, or set pluginsFile to false if a plugins file is not necessary for your project.

Error: Cannot find module 'cypress-cucumber-preprocessor'
Stack trace

plugins->index.js

```
const cucumber = require('cypress-cucumber-preprocessor').default;

/**
 * @type {Cypress.PluginConfig}
 */

module.exports = (on, config) => {
    require('cypress-mochawesome-reporter/plugin')(on);

    on('file:preprocessor', cucumber());

    on('before:browser:launch', (browser = {}, launchOptions) => {
        console.log(launchOptions.args);
        if (browser.family === 'chromium' && browser.name !== 'electron') {
            launchOptions.args.push('--start-fullscreen');
            launchOptions.args.push('--window-size=1400,1200');
        }

        if (browser.name === 'electron') {
            launchOptions.preferences.fullscreen = true;
        }

        if (browser.name === 'chrome' && browser.isHeadless) {
            launchOptions.args.push('--disable-gpu');
        }

        return launchOptions;
    });

    return config;
};
```

Comment: Have you installed `cypress-cucumber-preproccessor`? Is it in your package.json?

Comment: I solved it by npm install again